# Animate icon in GoJS

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a graph with nodes that contains icons:

```
$(go.TextBlock, {
  font: '18pt Material Icons', alignment: go.Spot.LeftCenter, stroke: '#FFFFFF',
  margin: new go.Margin(0, 5, 0, -34),
},
  new go.Binding('text', 'statusIcon')),
```

I would like to rotate statusIcon infinitly but only if `statusIcon` matchs a value.

I have looked how to add a css rule like this.

```
font: '18pt Material Icons', alignment: go.Spot.LeftCenter, stroke: '#FFFFFF',      
margin: new go.Margin(0, 5, 0, -34),animation:'spin 4s linear infinite';
```

But I get an error

> Trying to set undefined property "animation" on object: TextBlock

I suppose that only few css rules are accepted by gojs `TextBlock`.

How can I add animation to only a node sub element ?

Comment: I would be of great help if you can supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gojs-animation-trigger?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

```
$(go.TextBlock, {
  font: '18pt Material Icons', alignment: go.Spot.LeftCenter, stroke: '#FFFFFF',
  margin: new go.Margin(0, 5, 0, -34),
},
  new go.Binding('text', 'statusIcon'),
  new go.AnimationTrigger("angle")),

animate() {
    this.dia.commit(diag => {
      var node = this.dia.nodes.first();
      var textblock = node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK_TO_ROTATE");
      textblock.angle = textblock.angle + 30;
    });
  }
```

Animation is not a property like you used above. If you want to rotate, you should use `AnimationTrigger` and `angle` property for that.
I made a simple example to use GoJS animation, you can apply the codes from node template of TextBlock and the method to animate as you wish.

For more information, you can follow the description and the examples [here](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/animation.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make animation run infinitly ?

Comment: There is another Animation class which can run infinitely. **I updated the StackBlitz** for animation running infinitely, [link is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gojs-animation-vs-animation-trigger).